# Show defaul splash screen wp8

Tags: windows-phone-8, default, splash-screen

I'd like to show the default splash screen whenever i want... not only when the app is launched or reactivated...

I've found different solutions to create custom splash screen but they are much more i really need... for example here

http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Custom_splash_screen_with_progress_bar_for_Windows_Phone_applications

Can anyone help me to find a solution please?
Thanx...

Comment: can you elaborate on whenever ? is it going to be triggered by the user or by some background event ?

Comment: The link that you have shown is pretty simple, i doubt its going to be simpler than that

Comment: yes the link is difficult... but it is not what I need... i do not need a custom splash screen.. I need the default splash screen, with its own style... with no need to replicate it and do it the same... It should appear after a user choose a photo.. I take the stream and i do some processing... during processing it is shown a black screen... i would like to show the default splash screen instead...
thank you

Comment: If you want splash screen again, why cant you make it as a view and navigate to that whenever you want.

Comment: I would advise against the splashscreen showing when you process an image. It'll only confuse the user; why not make the system tray's progressbar visible? Set that to indeterminate and you're ready to go; the user then knows that something is happening and they'll have to wait.